# JQuery mask not working properly

Tags: jquery, masking

I have a problem with mask in jquery, I want to make a mask that will allows me to input any letter 0-n times.
I have something like this:

```
$.mask.definitions['@']='[A-Za-z]';
$('#textMask').mask("@@@@@@@@@@");
```

But with my code I could insert only to ten characters. anyone have an idea If it is of course possible?

I think about something like this:

```
$('#textMask').mask("@*");
```

but this allows me to insert one letter and one no matter what character. e.g d5 etc.
In brief I want to allow user to type a text containing only letters.
e.g.

```
abcdEEEE
abRFdas
a
 //empty field
bfdjksgbjfdsgbjklfbjklfgnfljkgbnhlfsdjgnfdlskgnfdsgfhsdlgdf
...
```

etc.

I used JQuery 1.10.3 and plugin version 1.3.1 (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: Assuming this plugin uses Regex syntax, have you tried `"@+"`?

Comment: if i changed it to "@+" I'm able to type 'leter'+ e.g
a+
A+
b+
g+ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [JQuery Mask plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) if you apply `mask` method on `<input>` field, automatically `maxlength` attribute is assigned to it. So when you do `$('#textMask').mask("@*");` then you get something like `<input id='textMask' maxlength='2'/>`. To avoid this you can set `maxlength` attribute on mask. In the other hand to achieve the 0-n times you can use `recursive` attribute. So finally to accept letter 0-n times:

```
$('#textMask').mask('@', { 'translation' : { '@' : { pattern : /[A-Za-z]/, recursive: true, }}, maxlength : false });
```

Take in account that if you previously make a `mask` on your input field probably `maxlength` attribute is set and specifying `maxlength : false` not unset this attribute (I think this is like a bug), so previously apply `unmask()` on your element.

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

What version of JQuery and plugin mask are you using? I use 1.11.0 of JQuery and 1.7.4 of plugin mask and works correctly check [this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq3tx9j0/)

Hope this helps,

Comment: #albciff no I didn't previously mask it. I paste the code which You post but it didn't work properly, it still works like I have $('#textMask').mask('@'); and I'm able only to type one letter.

Comment: @LEEL this works for me, check your jquery and mask plugin version. If you want check it out jfiddle sample that I put in the answer.

Comment: maybe it's because I don't use html input but grails textfield. <g:textField id="name" name="name" /> ?
#edit
If I changed to input nothing happened :c

Comment: Okey I have no more patience for this and changed my prev mask plugin to this one what You post @albciff. Thanks :)!

Comment: I see you last answer edit, you are using a different mask plugin (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js), If it's possible try with http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/